# USB NIC cause: *** buffer overflow detected ***: python terminated

Tags: networking, usb, adapter, nic

debugging a lot my software (python+compiledC++) on different machines (workstations and laptops with same OS **Ubuntu 18.04** 64 bit) I figured out that by using my **USB Type C Network adapter** (and the same by using a USB Type B NIC) I got the message:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: python terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Unfortunately I don't have a native NIC on my 14 inches laptop and I need to use the USB adapter. I tested the software on a Workstation and it works by using the motherboard NIC while it reports the same error message trying the USB NIC on that.

Does anybody knows how to increase the size of the buffer within the adapter?

I tried something like:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=33554432
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=33554432
```

but doesn't help.

Many thanks for any hints.

Cheers,
Andrea

EDIT: just to add some info, I use the latest kernel release either on workstation and laptop